# Sign custom buildtype with a generic debug keystore

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-keystore, android-build-type

Is it possible to create a custom buildtype and use the debug's keystore to sign it?

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }

    debug {
        debuggable true
        // debug specific configs here
    }

    staging {
        // staging specific configs here
    }
}
```

I tried setting `debubbable true` for my staging but did not work. I cannot use the `initWith` config because `debug` configs could interfere with my `staging` configs. I know I can create a `signingConfig` but this involves creating a separate key. I am looking at using the debug's default keystore.

Help please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try this:

```
staging {
    signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    ...
}
```

Comment: You are awesome!